# Laravel AutoHydrate Ardent Model, but sometimes manually assign?

Tags: laravel-4, ardent

So I have my Model setup like this:

```
protected $fillable = array('dragon_id', 'name', 'gender');

public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true;    // hydrates on new entries' validation
public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true; // hydrates whenever validation is called
```

However in ONE instance, I need to manually assign some of the attributes.. is there a way to do this? Because when I manually assign with auto hydrate set to true, it overwrites what I manually set.

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, if you set `public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = false;` (or comment out completely) then you can call:

```
$newModel = MyModelClass::create(arrayOfAttributes);
```

And it will not auto hydrate.